# No sign of Community Promotion Ads - 2015?

Tags: support, community-promotion-ads

Previously, in early December, a special post would go out to each of the public Meta sites (*except, perhaps, StackOverflow) asking the community to suggest and vote for Community Promotion Ads for the following year.

We haven't seen one this year yet. Should we be preparing our range of adverts in readiness for one of these posts that is just running a little late, or is there something new in store for us in 2015?

Comment: Stop Press: The special posts went out. This is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Should we be preparing our range of adverts in readiness for one of these posts that is just running a little late, or is there something new in store for us in 2015?

Nothing fundamentally new that I know of. 'tis the season for vacations, though, so the posts will go up Soon<sup>TM</sup>. Have your ads at the ready.

Comment: Probably around 6-8 weeks, eh?